# Is there a way to host two different clients on localhost:80 simultaniously

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, vite, .net-4.8

We're working on a migration project where we're moving from ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.7 Framework (referred to as legacy) to a .NET 7 Core as backend and React (with Vite) as frontend.

We need to it do progressively as the project is quite big.

We're at the stage where we have done 90% frontend migration from ASP.NET MVC to React and about 60% of the backend as been moved to .NET 7.

To give you more context: our current React is rendered not as a real SPA but each View in the legacy project render its own React bundle.

The mission I have been assigned to is to move our React to a real SPA rendered inside the .NET 7 app (which is already setup to support a SPA project).

The issue I run into is that even if I moved enough React to the new backend, some pages still remains (like the dev connection or the administration page) inside the legacy project. So I asked my referent how should both of the clients should be served he told me the following : Each pages of the React must be on XXXXX/pro/pageA and legacy pages must be on XXXXX/pageB. (XXXXX being the same address like localhost)

So my question is: how can I achieve this kind of behaviour? As my React is served via the .NET 7 project and the legacy project still serve some asp pages as views.

Here is my Vite config :

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
  },
  base: '/pro',
  server: {
    strictPort: true,
    port: 80,
    host: true
  }
});
```

Here is an extract of the .NET 7 Program.cs file :

```
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(filesOptions => filesOptions.RootPath = "ClientApp/build"); 
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.Run();
```

Here is my `launchSettings.json` of the .NET 7 project:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/pro"
    },

    "profiles": {
       "WebPro": {
          "commandName": "Project",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
          "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
       }
    },
}
```

And the `.csproj` of the .NET 7 app looks like this :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>WebPro</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>WebPro</AssemblyName>
        <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
        <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
        <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
        <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
        <SpaProxyServerUrl>http://localhost:80/pro</SpaProxyServerUrl>
        <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm run dev</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>

        <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
        <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
        <UserSecretsId>efad71c6-743c-4b87-9de8-f26d77146f6d</UserSecretsId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="10.3.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="7.0.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="NewRelic.LogEnrichers.Serilog" Version="1.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.10.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="4.10.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.10.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.10.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.10.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
        <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
        <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
        <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <RunPostBuildEvent>OnBuildSuccess</RunPostBuildEvent>
    </PropertyGroup>

    
    <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
      <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
      <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
      </Exec>
      <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
      <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
      <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
      <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
      <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
      <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

      <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
      <ItemGroup>
        <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**" />
        <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
          <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
          <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
        </ResolvedFileToPublish>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

As for the legacy project, it is already configured to run on localhost/pageB.

The result is that my asp launch normally but the .NET 7 web app just won't run the Vite project.

If I try to launch the Vite project apart, it tells me that the port 80 is already in use.

Any answer or even clue is really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When you say "run the Vite project" do you mean the vite CLI? In development, if using the separate vite dev server, you'd usually configure that on a different port and then have Vite proxy requests that don't begin with `/pro` to the server, by configuring it do so: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy.

Comment: Obviously, in production, there is no vite CLI. For production, routes need to be added on the back end such that any wildcard URL under `/pro/*` would serve the production-built vite `index.html` from port 80, all on the same server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
From what you are telling me,  in dev, I need to host my legacy on smth like port 4444 and for each request and/or navigation that is not made under /pro, redirect via the vite proxy to this specific port ?